# Terraform tool, terraformer

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

we are using terraform on AWS and we would like to start importing the already existing infra. We found a tool called `terraformer`, and i would like to ask if anyone knows if it can import the AWS `nat gateways` that already exists in our infra?
Thank you very much.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

The open-sourced tool that is commonly used for generation of CloudFormation and Terraform templates from existing sources is [Former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2):

> Generate CloudFormation / Terraform / Troposphere templates from your existing AWS resources

Thus, I would first recommend looking at this tool if it meets your requirements.